Read and update JSON File in Azure Data Factory (ADF)
I am trying to read a JSON File (a Control File, to get the dataset names) and after processing each dataset i want to update the JSON back into the Storage Location.
My JSON looks like this.
[
  {
    "SchemaName": "MySchema",
    "TableName": "Table1",
    "SearchColumn": "Created_Date",
    "LastLoadDate": ""
  },
  {
    "SchemaName": "MySchema",
    "TableName": "Table2",
    "SearchColumn": "Updated_Date",
    "LastLoadDate": "2010-06-06T00:00:00"
  }
]

What i want to do inside a foreach loop, is when the Table processing is complete, the JSON file should be updated with the current date for that "TableName".  ("LastLoadDate" should change to Current Date)
I am able to read and process everything fine, the only issue is that i am not able to create a JSON String and save it back to the Storage in JSON format using copy activity.
I cannot use dataflows for technical limitations in the organisation. So i have to do it via the Copy activity.
My plan is as follows.

Create a string with all the JSON Values
i have done it throug the below code

Variable JSONObjectString is created
@concat('{"SchemaName":', item().SchemaName, '","TableName":', item().TableName,'","SearchColumn":', item().SearchColumn,'","LastLoadDate":', utcNow(),'"}')


Append the above string to a string variable "UdpatedJSONString"
@concat(variables('JSONArray'),variables('JSONObjectString'))

Once the Loop is completed, outside the loop convert the Array to JSON (Thats where the code is failing)
@json(string(variables('UdpatedJSONString')))
Error:
The variable 'UdatedJSONString' of type 'String' cannot be initialized or updated with value of      type 'Array'. The variable 'ResultJSON' only supports values of types 'String'.

Write the Converted JSON Array to the storage location (Replace the existing file).


I have tried several ways of converting the Array into String to before converting it into JSON. but none of them worked.
Need help with the complete code for this. Thanks

You can achieve your requirement by following the below approach.
Currently, Append variable activity only supports to adding to an array variable. So, first create an array variable without any default value in the pipeline variable section. You can ignore the second variable here which I have created just for showing the result.

Inside For-each, use append variable activity on this variable with below expression.
@json(concat('{"SchemaName":"',item().SchemaName, '","TableName":"',item().TableName,'","SearchColumn":"',item().SearchColumn,'","LastLoadDate":"',utcnow(),'"}'))


Here, it is directly appending the JSON object in each iteration and the required JSON array will be stored in the JSON_array variable at the end of the For loop. You need to make sure Sequential is checked in your For-each activity otherwise, this will append in random order.
For just result showing, I have used another variable and the JSON will be generated like below.

Currently, in ADF you cannot directly create a JSON file from JSON variable. You can try the workaround mentioned in this SO answer. Here, use a csv file to generate the required JSON file.
This requires a dummy temporary csv file from Blob with any single value like below which can act as a source of the copy activity.

Create a delimited text dataset for the above file and uncheck First Row as header in the dataset.
For the target JSON file, create another Delimited text dataset with following configurations. Give your target file path and its name in this csv dataset.

Now, give the above datasets as source and sink datasets for the copy activity. In the copy activity source, create an additional column new with dynamic expression @string(variables('JSON_array')) like below.

Give the below dynamic expression as the mapping of the copy activity.
@json('{
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "mappings": [
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "name": "new",
                                                "type": "String"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String",
                                                "ordinal": 1
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }')


Here, Upon the pipeline run, it will add JSON as string column to the dummy csv file. But due to the mapping, it will delete the original single value from the dummy csv file and process only given JSON as a string column. As per the given configurations in the target csv dataset, the JSON file will be generated. If it's already there, it will be overwritten with the updated JSON.
JSON file:

